# Use value of a string to create new form object

Tags: c#, winforms, string

I have a main form that is launched and then it can go to any of the other forms I have created. But the kicker is that I have written a class that I call that returns a string with the name of the form to go to.

Currently I don't have this working so I am going from form to form like this (statically written linking code):

```
this.Hide();
CloudAccess nextForm1 = new CloudAccess(); 
   //Where CloudAccess is the class of the next form.
nextForm1.ShowDialog();
```

What I want is something like this:

```
FormController pick = new FormController();
   //Where FormController is the Class I create an object of and ask what's next
string next = pick.whereToGo(); //lets say it returns "CloudAccess"
this.Hide();
next nextForm1 = new next(); //next is desired to be the contents of the string
nextForm1.ShowDialog();
```

The problem is that I don't know how to use the returned string to make the new object and use it. I've been looking at Invoke and Reflection topics like this one: [Use string value to create new instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778229/use-string-value-to-create-new-instance)
But I'm new to C# and I'm not sure how to apply that to this scenario.

Thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Just have whereToGo() return a Form, not a string.  Controllers should never ever have a problem creating view instances.

Comment: How would I go about having it return a form?
public form whereToGo(){
return CloudAccess;
} ?

Comment: @Dial - it doesn't answer the question.  Operating the two-by-four to the forehead is best done in comments, in my experience.

Comment: @Hans It would be an answer because it'd allow me to get to the same result. I'm just not sure how I'd have the method a form..

Comment: @cvo - that goes full circle: why do you have a controller in your code that doesn't know how to create views?  Is the object model getting in the way of getting the job done?  I have no idea why of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the working code from what fejejosco said:

```
string asdf = "CloudAccess";
Type CAType = Type.GetType("namespace." + asdf);
Form nextForm2 = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(CAType);
nextForm2.ShowDialog();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Get the type of the form: `Type.GetType("name.space." + formname)`, so if your class is `name.space.CloudAccessForm`, then pass in `CloudAccessForm` as formname, and it will give you the type. Then you can instantiate it with `Activator.CreateInstance(type)`. Then cast it to a `Form`, and show it.

Comment: string asdf = "CloudAccess";
Type CAType = Type.GetType("NameSpace." + asdf);
Activator.CreateInstance(CAType);
Form nextForm2 = (Form)CAType;
nextForm2.ShowDialog();
this gives me the error: "Cannot convert type 'System.Type' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'

Comment: Cast the instance, not the type.