# Simplify methods that differ by different used Form type and Form name into one generic method

Tags: c#, winforms, generics

I have several buttons that all have the same code, the only difference is the form name that is used.  I'm trying to find a way to make the code smaller so instead of using the same code in every button and change the form name and type if I could pass the string name to a method with generics I could then shorten the code a lot.

current code (the only thing that changes is the frmVPNManager

```
private void rbtnVPNManager_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var frm = Application.OpenForms["frmVPNManager"] as frmVPNManager;
    if (frm != null)
    {
        frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        frm.BringToFront();
        frm.Activate();
    }
    else
    {
        frm = new frmVPNManager() { MdiParent = this };
        if (rbnMain.OrbDropDown.RecentItems.All(item => item.Text != frm.Text))
        {
            var rbtn = new RibbonButton { Text = frm.Text, DrawIconsBar = false, MaxSizeMode = RibbonElementSizeMode.Medium, SmallImage = Properties.Resources.preview_24x24 };
            rbtn.Click += (s, ea) =>
            {
                var frmv = Application.OpenForms["frmVPNManager"] as frmVPNManager;
                if (frmv != null)
                {
                    frmv.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
                    frmv.BringToFront();
                    frmv.Activate();
                }
                else
                {
                    rbnMain.OrbDropDown.RecentItems.RemoveAll(item => item.Text == frm.Text);
                }
            };
            rbnMain.OrbDropDown.RecentItems.Add(rbtn);
        }
        frm.Show();
        frm.BringToFront();
        frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    }
}
```

I've attempted using generics but I don't know enough on how to get this to work, any suggestions?  I should also state that the following line does not work
var frm = new T { MdiParent = this };

```
private void rbtnVPNManager_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    formtest<frmVPNManager>("frmVPNManager");
}
private void rbtnVPNList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    formtest<frmVPNList>("frmVPNList");
}
private void formtest<T>(string formname)
{
    if (Application.OpenForms[formname] != null)
    {
        var frm = Application.OpenForms[formname];
        if (frm is T)
        {
            frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            frm.BringToFront();
            frm.Activate();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var frm = new T { MdiParent = this };

        if (rbnMain.OrbDropDown.RecentItems.All(item => item.Text != frm.Text))
        {
            var rbtn = new RibbonButton { Text = frm.Text, DrawIconsBar = false, MaxSizeMode = RibbonElementSizeMode.Medium, SmallImage = Properties.Resources.preview_24x24 };
            rbtn.Click += (s, ea) =>
            {
                var frmv = Application.OpenForms[formname] as T;
                if (frmv != null)
                {
                    frmv.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
                    frmv.BringToFront();
                    frmv.Activate();
                }
                else
                {
                    rbnMain.OrbDropDown.RecentItems.RemoveAll(item => item.Text == frm.Text);
                }
            };
            rbnMain.OrbDropDown.RecentItems.Add(rbtn);
        }

        frm.Show();
        frm.BringToFront();
        frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying the form that the button relates to is specific to the button? if so create a subclass of button that has a property relating  to the form it needs to invoke and then create a shared handler.

Comment: Also, whats not working?

Comment: @derape - It is working, OP is looking for a way to make his code more maintainable.

Comment: @derape the original method works, as Sayse said I am looking to better maintain the code, however that said the following code won't work var frm = new T { MdiParent = this };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [generic restrictions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) on your generic [type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype(v=vs.110).aspx) of the Form.

```
// This is the overload that uses default name for your form generated using the Type name
private void formtest<T>() 
    where T : Form, new
{
    formtest<T>(typeof(T).Name); // assume that type of the form is the name of the form instance.
}

// Here we use first overload that uses default name for the form
private void rbtnVPNList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    formtest<frmVPNList>();
}


// This is your original code with generic restrictions. Here you can specify name for the form that differs from its type name.
private void formtest<T>(String formname) 
    where T : Form, new
{
    if (Application.OpenForms[formname] != null)
    {
        var frm = Application.OpenForms[formname];
        if (frm is T)
        {
            frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            frm.BringToFront();
            frm.Activate();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var frm = new T() { MdiParent = this };

    if (rbnMain.OrbDropDown.RecentItems.All(item => item.Text != frm.Text))
    {
        var rbtn = new RibbonButton { Text = frm.Text, DrawIconsBar = false, MaxSizeMode = RibbonElementSizeMode.Medium, SmallImage = Properties.Resources.preview_24x24 };
        rbtn.Click += (s, ea) =>
        {
            var frmv = Application.OpenForms[formname] as T;
            if (frmv != null)
            {
                frmv.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
                frmv.BringToFront();
                frmv.Activate();
            }
            else
            {
                rbnMain.OrbDropDown.RecentItems.RemoveAll(item => item.Text == frm.Text);
            }
        };
        rbnMain.OrbDropDown.RecentItems.Add(rbtn);
    }

    frm.Show();
    frm.BringToFront();
    frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    }
 }
```

**P.S.**: Just make sure that your forms' [Names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.name(v=vs.110).aspx) are consistent. You could use base intermediate class for your forms with constructor like:

```
public abstract class FormBase : Form
{
     public FormBase()
     {
          // Constructor code
          this.Name = this.GetType().Name;
     }
}

public class myFrvForm : Form
{
     public myFrvForm() // base constructor will set name of the form to appropriate one
     {
     }
}
```

Comment: Great answer, however I forgot to mention that the re-written code above doesn't work as you cant do frm = new T { MdiParent = this };

Comment: also new should be new()

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, you just need to add generic constraint to formtest:

```
private void formtest<T>(string formname) where T : Form, new()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using "this", you need to make a non-static copy of the method for each form you're using it in. My idea is to write the `Form's name` to the used button's `Tag`-property in the designer. The name needs to be exactly the same as the form's class name.:

```
    private void sharedButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        buttonFunction(((Button)sender).Tag.ToString());
    }

    private void buttonFunction(string formName)
    {
        Form frm = Application.OpenForms[formName] as Form;
        if (frm != null)
        {
            frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            frm.BringToFront();
            frm.Activate();
        }
        else
        {
            // Open right form according to formName
            Type CAType = Type.GetType("yournamespacehere." + formName);
            frm = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(CAType);
            frm.MdiParent = this;

            if (rbnMain.OrbDropDown.RecentItems.All(item => item.Text != frm.Text))
            {
                var rbtn = new RibbonButton { Text = frm.Text, DrawIconsBar = false, MaxSizeMode = RibbonElementSizeMode.Medium, SmallImage = Properties.Resources.preview_24x24 };
                rbtn.Click += (s, ea) =>
                {
                    var frmv = Application.OpenForms["frmVPNManager"] as Form;
                    if (frmv != null)
                    {
                        frmv.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
                        frmv.BringToFront();
                        frmv.Activate();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rbnMain.OrbDropDown.RecentItems.RemoveAll(item => item.Text == frm.Text);
                    }
                };
                rbnMain.OrbDropDown.RecentItems.Add(rbtn);
            }
            frm.Show();
            frm.BringToFront();
            frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        }
    }
```

This code uses https://stackoverflow.com/a/4576428/2538037 to resolve the form according to given name. I haven't tested this. Use `sharedButton_Click`on your buttons.